# Maven modules that require versioning

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, maven-3

I created a new project with the org.wildfly.archetype:wildfly-jakartaee-ear-archetype:27.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT archetype and then added a library module to get the following project structure:

```
project
+-->project-ear
+-->project-ejb
+-->project-lib
+-->project-web
```

However, in my project-lib/pom.xml file the dependency for this new library requires a version, where as the EJB and WEB modules do not. Why? And is there a way to configure the *project-lib/pom.xml* so that the *project-ear/pom.xml* doesn't require a version on a library that is part of the same project?

Snippet of project/pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>project</name>
<modules>
    <module>project-lib</module>
    <module>project-ejb</module>
    <module>project-web</module>
    <module>project-ear</module>
</modules>
```

Snippet of project-ear/pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>project-ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-tfl</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>   <--- Line I wish to remove! -->
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-ejb</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-web</artifactId>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Snippet of project-lib/pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>project-lib</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
```

Comment: Please make a full example of the project on github or alike...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for you time. A project demoing the issue is here: https://github.com/dobbo/example-project.git . If you look in the project-ear/pom.xml file there is a comment, like my OP that I wish to remove.

Comment: create a pull request to your repository... there are a lot of things which are not the best way to go...You can define the dependency in the root pom via dependencyManagement which would make the definition of the version in the child module obsolete...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for looking at the example. Yes nothing is used because it is a minimum project that is there just to show this issue I have; which it failed because I didn't push the update with the library added. 'Doh. Now pushed,